# Geometric interpretation of limit on a complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I read on wikipedia it said that complex function is function from complex number to complex number.
We already know that complex number is $a+ib$ it's like real part crossed with imaginary part.
I'm confuse here.
Is that mean complex function is 4D? 
Besides that, wikipedia said $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can be docomposed by $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
In other words it can be interpreted on 3D plane?

And what is the interpretation of limit on a complex plane? I saw on some books that many of them use $z$ approaches to $z_0$. And $z_0$ defined  by $x_0 +i y_0$.
It's mean that complex limit use limit of 2 variables that is represented on 3 dimensional right?
A lot of confusion here. Please gimme some good explanations.

Comment: Yes, if you want to graph a function $f\colon\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, you'll need a four-dimensional world. Since we can draw reasonable pictures of 3D objects on paper (or a computer screen), all you need is a 3-dimensional piece of paper and you'll be able to draw 4D. I have no idea what your sentence "can be decomposed by" from wiki is supposed to mean. You can, however, graph the real part of $f$, as this will be a map $\Bbb C\to\Bbb R$ and then graph the imaginary part separately. But it takes imagination to interpolate from these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decomposing $n$-Dimensional Functions**

*In general*, if you have a function...

$$\displaystyle f:\prod_{i=0}^m X_i\to\prod_{j=0}^n Y_j$$

...you can decompose it into $n$ (or fewer) functions...

$$\displaystyle f_k:\prod_{i=0}^m X_i\to Y_k$$

For example, if you have $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^3$, where

$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy,x)$$

you can break $f$ into the three functions:

$$f_1(x,y)=x^2-y^2$$

$$f_2(x,y)=2xy$$

$$f_3(x,y)=x$$

Since every complex number can be represented as a pair of real numbers by $a+bi\mapsto(a,b)$, you can think of a function $\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ instead as a function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$. In this sense, a complex function is indeed "four-dimensional." However, since you can decompose any function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ into two functions $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$, you can likewise decompose any complex function into two "three-dimensional" functions $\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{R}$.

Be aware, however, that "dimension" is defined differently in different contexts. What you are referring to is the "real dimension" of a vector space (in this case the complex numbers are a vector space with real dimension $2$). The "complex dimension" of the complex numbers is still $1$.

**Graphing Complex Functions**

Generally, there are three ways to represent a complex function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$.

The first is as a vector field (no different from a vector-valued function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$). For a function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$, the vector field is given by $(\Re(z),\Im(z))\mapsto(\Re[f(z)],\Im[f(z)])$, where $\Re(z)$ is the real part of $z$ and $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part. The equivalent vector-valued function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto(\Re[f(x+yi)],\Im[f(x+yi)]):$

[image]

The second method is to use two surfaces, one representing the real value of the function at a point $x+yi$, the other representing the imaginary value. Each surface is defined by decomposing the function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ into two functions $f_1:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ and $f_2:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$.

[image]

The third way is to use a surface representing the real value of the function at a point and to color the surface to indicate its imaginary value at that point (or vice-versa) - or to plot the absolute value and color it according to the phase/complex argument as shown below. This might be the most common visualization of complex functions.

[image]

There are other ways to represent complex functions graphically, but I find that these are more artistic than they are informative (especially for the color-blind and/or visually impaired). Many excellent examples of different types of visualization can be found on the Wikimedia pages [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Complex_functions) and [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Complex_algebraic_curves_and_Riemann_surfaces).

**Limits in the Complex Plane**

The limit of a complex function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ at a point $z_0\in\Bbb{C}$ can likewise be represented a number of ways. If you are taking the limit visually (assuming you are using a computer), then I would suggest looking at a surface plot of the real part of $f$ and finding the apparent value at $z_0$, then doing the same with the imaginary part and adding them together.

This is the same as showing that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\Re[f(z)]+i\lim_{z\to z_0}\Im[f(z)]$

If your looking at the limit of a sequence, it's common to plot the points of the sequence in the complex plane (like you would a parametric curve in $\Bbb{R}^2$) rather than against an axis (like you would a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$).

Since a complex sequence is a function $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{C}$ you may think of it as "three-dimensional" - or as two functions $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{R}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer sensei.